# Constructor from base not found

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2017

```
#include <string_view>

class str_ref : public std::string_view
{
public:
  using std::string_view::string_view;
};

int main()
{
  std::string_view sv;
  str_ref sr("", 0);
  str_ref sr2(sv); // error C2664: 'str_ref::str_ref(const str_ref &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string_view' to 'const char *const '
}
```

Why is the constructor for (string_view) not being found here? Shouldn't this constructor be imported with the using statement? The (const char*, size_t) constructor is being found.
I'm using VS2017.

Comment: because it is a template class

Comment: @dgrat Can you elaborate about that?

Comment: @dgrat no it's not. `std::string_view` is a full specialization of `std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>`

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't this constructor be imported with the using statement?

It is correctly imported, but you have to define that constuctor in the derived class yourself.
The compiler doesn't automatically generate a constructor like that for your derived class:

```
#include <string_view>

class str_ref : public std::string_view
{
public:
  using std::string_view::string_view;
  str_ref(const std::string_view& sv) : std::string_view(sv) {} // <<<<
};

int main()
{
  std::string_view sv;
  str_ref sr("", 0);
  str_ref sr2(sv);
}
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c1456caf0e50e75)

Comment: Excuse me, but what's the point of posting a duplicate answer (yes, I see the code) to an obviously duplicate question? You can close duplicates, right?

Comment: @iehrlich I didn't spot the dupe when I was writing my answer. Also having duplicates for upvoted questions isn't inherently bad. These may serve as signposts for future research.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)